# Applescript returns "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: " in Automator when it should be a string

Tags: string, applescript, automator, dialog

[image]Getting Result:

```
"<NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 1 ]>"
```

I have a Dialogue Box in an Applescript Shell in Automator

```
display dialog "¿ What database did you use for your sequences ?" buttons {"RefSeq", "Ensembl"} default button 2
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "RefSeq" then
    return 0
else if the button_pressed is "Ensembl" then
    return 1
end if
```

Why isn't it just printing the string?  I'm setting it to a variable using "Set to Variable" and then i'm getting the variable before my Python Shell Script using "Get the Variable"

in the Python Shell Script I simply use:

```
var_1 = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Do you realize you're saying you want a string returned but you're returning a number? Try putting quotes around the "1" and "0" to make them strings.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get it to print the string in Python?

This Python script prints “1” or “0” depending on the response to your AppleScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

script = '''
display dialog "¿ What database did you use for your sequences ?" buttons {"RefSeq", "Ensembl"} default button 2
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "RefSeq" then
    return 0
else if the button_pressed is "Ensembl" then
    return 1
end if
'''

macosx = Popen('/usr/bin/osascript', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(response, error) = macosx.communicate(script)
response = response.strip()

print response
```

For using this via “Run Shell Script” in Automator, the AppleScript, according to my reading of Apple’s [Creating Shell Script Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ShellScriptActions.html), must return values as strings. The Run Shell Script action doesn’t appear to perform [automatic type conversions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/CreateConversionAction.html).

In your example script, you can fix this by changing “return 0” and “return 1” to “return "0"” and “return "1"”:

[image: Run AppleScript return values must be strings]

I tested this both with the Set/Get Value of Variable actions and with a direct connection between Run AppleScript and Run Shell Script. The same behavior applied in each case.

Comment: Hey, Draconis. I updated the example for using AppleScript to return values to Run Shell Script in Automator. Surprisingly (to me, anyway), even though Automator has the functionality to perform type conversions, Run Shell Script doesn’t bother, and (if my reading is correct) requires all input to be strings.